# Анимация маятника

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток, решил смоделировать гармонические колебания математического маятника в python3, посредством несложных действий получил массивы x и y координат тела, подвешенного на нитку, однако никак не могу разобраться с графической частью, создать анимацию самого маятника. Буду рад любым идеям.

Результат 2D, схематичный,в виде видео, будет достаточно если смогу запустить через терминал на линухе. Я посмотрел различные библиотеки которые могут помочь мне, даже установил их, однако не нашел нигде доступного руководства того как это сделать. Вообще идея такая : просто закрепить одну точку прямой, а вторую прогнать по массиву координат.

Comment: Ну тут однозначно либо OpenCV либо Pygame. Там и там есть функции рисовать линию. В Pygame можно и спрайты рисовать и поворачивать легко.

Answer (score 2):

Для анимации можно воспользоваться библиотекой `turtle` в нем есть простые методы для рисования. Вам придется полностью в ручную отрисовывать каждый шаг анимации.

Также можно воспользоваться библиотекой `matplotlib`, в ней есть возможность создания анимации при помощи `FuncAnimation`. На сайте библиотеки есть пример [анимации двойного маятника](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html)